CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "path_provider_foundation"
when i run 'pod install
'this error occured,This has been bothering me for two days, can anyone help me? this is flutter for macos。
'''
pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "path_provider_foundation":
In Podfile:
path_provider_foundation (from Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/macos)
Specs satisfying the path_provider_foundation (from Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/macos) dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
'''
‘’‘platform :osx, '10.13'
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org'
’‘’
Apart from the official website of the path_provider_foundation library, I didn't find any problems with it.

Hard to answer without looking into pubspec.yaml file.
If the below suggestions do not work please share your pubspec.yaml file.
Suggestion One
rm -rf ios/Pods/
rm -rf ios/build/
rm -rf ios/Podfile.lock
    
pod install --repo-update

Suggestion Two
Update flutter and project dependencies. This might give you trouble if your project has not been upgraded for a very long time. But I highly recommend doing this.
flutter upgrade

# or if you are using home-brew
brew upgrade flutter

flutter pub upgrade --major-versions

I hope this helps.
